# How to set priority in queue in delayed job and Active job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

Let we have 2 queues: ffmpeg, default. In ffmpeg queue we have screenshot def, light video convertation , heavy convertation.So I want to start all screenshot job, all light convertation and after it heavy.As I understanded, from doc I can set one pool for 3 jobs in ffmpeg queue, but I can't prioritize it.I am only can set different queues and set priority for every queue, is it posible through Active Job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:priority => <priority_number>` when adding jobs to your ffmpeg queue.

Rails uses default 0 - 10 where 0 is highest priority. If you dont specify, your job will have 0 as priority